# Unix PATH override commands

Tags: bash, unix, environment-variables

Let's say my `PATH="/usr/bin ... /root/.rbenv/shims"`

I have an executable (ruby) in `/usr/bin` and `/root/.rbenv/shims`. How would I make the ruby in `/root/.rbenv/shims` be called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put `/root/.rbenv/shims` *first* in your `PATH`:

```
export PATH=/root/.rbenv/SHIMS:$PATH
```

(Before running this command, you must be sure `PATH` already exists -- if it doesn't, it adds the current working directory to your `PATH` *as well*, which is almost always a mistake.)

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute path:

```
$ /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby ...
```

If you're doing this from a shell script, then use

```
#!/root/.rbenc/shims/ruby
```

as the shebang