# Why can I no longer use my regular git bash commands after activating conda?

Tags: windows, conda, git-bash

I installed conda on my wind10. Now, when I open git bash, conda is automatically activated. This is ok, and I know how to remove it from my settings, so it will not be automatically started.

The problem now is, that I can no longer run any of my other commands in bash except the basic git bash commands.

It will no longer recognize my .bashrc commands nor any installed programms like `code`, `notepad`, `explorer` or `git` unless I deactivate conda again.

Comment: seems problem in `PATH` environment variable setup. read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206727/unix-path-override-commands